# Problem with using AWS ACL with AWS S3 SYNC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a requirement to upload one of the jar files into the AWS s3 bucket if it is not updated by one of the previous processes. So I'm using the below command to upload the jar file along with the AWS ACL option.
But the ACL option is not applied here and I'm still facing the issue with accessing this jar from the AWS. Is something wrong with the below command?

```
aws s3 sync /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ s3://test.bucket/config/ --exclude "*" --include "service-0.1.0.jar" --acl bucket-owner-full-control
```

Comment: What do you mean by "if it is not updated by one of the previous processes"? The `sync` command will copy files that have been added or modified since a previous sync (basically, where the source file doesn't match a file in the destination). Worst case, you could use `cp` instead of `sync` and just force the copy.

Answer (score 0):

Your command works fine for me.  You should check that you have permissions to adjust the ACL

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html

> --acl (string) Sets the ACL for the object when the command is performed. **If you use this parameter you must have the "s3:PutObjectAcl" permission included in the list of actions for your IAM policy**. Only accepts values of private, public-read, public-read-write, authenticated-read, aws-exec-read, bucket-owner-read, bucket-owner-full-control and log-delivery-write. See Canned ACL for details